# Is it possible to add a callback to eval(data);?

Tags: javascript, jquery

So when eval(data) is complete, how would you set a callback?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Eval is not asynchronous, so you don't need a callback. Just put your function call on the next line.

The script you are evalling might do something asynchronous, in which case you would need to parse the JS, find the asynchronous code, and add a callback to that (in string form).

Best to avoid eval in the first place though. It is almost never the right solution to a problem.

Comment: Its a tough call about eval(data) as a good choice, because I'm calling an asynchronous request after the js has been loaded. But if I do clean my XSS, is there something more to worry about? And do you recommend any alternatives?

Comment: eval is difficult to debug, has scoping issues and is just plain slow. I can't suggest an alternative solution - I don't know the problem, only the function you think can solve it.

Comment: +1 for "Best to avoid eval in the first place." Eval can create a bunch of problems (including security risks, makes it very difficult to minify code, etc).

Comment: @JasCav - if `eval` is used solely on the client, I don't see how it's any more of a security risk than opening up the browser's JavaScript console.

Answer (score 1):

Just put the code you want to execute on callback in the data that is going to be evaluated. Of course you will have problem if in the evaluated data you have some dynamic generated function that runs asynchronously.

Comment: I'm trying to be outside of the `data`

Comment: Why? You can user data += 'my_function();'

Answer (score 1):

`eval(data)` is a blocking call. All you have to do is put your "callback" code after your `eval()` call, and it will be executed once the `eval()` is finished.